# fwrite Binary Stream to char array or string

Tags: c++, redirect, stream, binary, fwrite

```
    size = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&src, &srclen);
    /*stuff*/
    fwrite(buf, size, 1, stdout);
```

I obtain a message using recvfrom() and am able to output to stdout via fwrite, but I need to store the data that I am currently just outputting to the console. What's the best method for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the binary data may contain nulls, you can't use usual string conversion or c-string functions (risk of partial copy).  The solution would be to:

```
char *pbuf = new char[size]; 
if (pbuf) 
   std::copy(buf, buf+size, pbuf);  
// then store the pointer somewhere
```

It uses [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/), which takes the begin and end of the reginon to copy it, so it's appropriate for binary data.